# Firing repeating events on Touch Down in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, nsoperation

I am working on an application where I want to call a method every few seconds whilst the user has their finger on a button, and stops on release.

At the moment I am setting off an NSOperation on the Touch Down event, which should then call an NSTimer to fire another NSOperation 2 seconds later.

However only the first "runOperation" is happening; the ones from the timer aren't.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self doStuff];
}

- (void)runOperation {
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(doStuff)
                                                                          object:nil];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}

- (void)doStuff {
    /* stuff goes here */

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)setTimer
{
    timer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.f target:self selector:@selector(runOperation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}

- (IBAction)finishTakingPictures:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, hope this helps you out, don't know why I spent so much time on this... :)

If you use `NSTimer:timerWithTimeInterval:...` you need to add the timer to a run loop using `NSRunLoop:addTimer:forMode`. That's why your timer isn't firing. If you use `NSTimer:scheduledTimerWithTimeInerval:...` it will be added to the current run loop.

A few thoughts on your implementation.

1. You have lots of indirection. You can set it directly in `doStuff` and get rid of the `setTimer` method.
2. There's no reason to set the timer on the main thread, you can set it on any thread.
3. You don't really need a timer at all, I'll suggest an alternate implementation below.

ALTERNATE IMPLEMENTATION:

1. Add a BOOL property e.g. `@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFinished;`
2. When the user presses the button, set `isFinished = NO;` and start your first operation.
3. When the operation completes, if `isFinished == NO` start another operation. You can add a delay by using `performSelector:afterDelay:` or using `dispatch_after()`
4. When the user stops pressing the button, set `isFinished = YES`

This alternate implementation assumes you want to start the next operation after the first is complete. If you want the operation to happen after a fixed interval independent of whether an operation is already processing change your timer to repeat and when the timer fires check `isFinished == YES` to invalidate the timer.

Comment: doh doh and doh again; how did I miss that wrt to adding the timer to the runloop! yes, lots of needless indirection (result of lots of mucking about failing to see the real problem, and setting timer on main thread was clutching at straws).

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, i'd accept both replies if I could but NJones' is probably closer to the implementation I'll use. That said, always good to see an alternate approach.

Comment: Glad you're learning. WRT SO, a few thoughts. Generally, you should accept the first correct answer unless a later one is far superior. I don't care about the few points, saying this on principle. My answer was correct and I told you how to fix the problem. All the additional stuff is gravy. @NJones answer is fine, it's only a slight tweak on mine. In this case it's ok, but there are times when you wouldn't want to track state using a view property (e.g. when the view could go away while the operation was still in progress). Lastly, you can upvote as many answers as you like. Happy coding.

Comment: Noted, thanks again (although you can only up vote once you have 15 reputation).

Answer (score 2):

XJones (no relation) is right about the scheduled timer, and about the ridiculous amount of indirection. But I personally do like the NSTimer for this user interaction model. Here is how I would implement it.

```
_buttonTimer is an instance variable,
button is an IBOutlet to the button in question,
touchDown: is connected to the button's TouchDown event.
```

Adding the button as an outlet removes the need to have a BOOL to track the button state since the button knows it's state.

Then add these methods to your UIViewController subclass.

```
-(void)helloMe{
    if (self.button.state == UIControlStateNormal){ 
        [_buttonTimer invalidate];
        _buttonTimer = nil
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Hello me");
        // Do stuff here
    }
}

- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    _buttonTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(helloMe) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [_buttonTimer fire]; // If desired
}
```

Now run you will see "Hello me" in the console upon the push of the button and every two seconds until you release the button.